# How to set up Devise to use the same users table from two different Applications

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to set up Devise to use the same users table from two diffrent applications. We will have both applications tables in the same database. They won't share the same session details as these will most likely be in separate root domains.
Any idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this by using `connection_ninja` gem 
kindly checkout 
[connection_ninja](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja) on github